# Getting app version is crashing in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am having this code to get the app version and save it to `nsdictionary`:

```
    NSString *Version=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]];

    NSLog(@"VERSION%@",Version); //prints the right thing
    NSMutableDictionary *dic;
    [dic setValue:Version forKey:@"version"]; //crash 
    [dic setValue:Errors forKey:@"errors"]; //work
```

The error I get on crash is:

```
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key version
```

How can I identify this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to allocate the dictionary :

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not `alloc`+`init`-ed the dictionary `dict`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

That is must.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create the dictionary. Since it's (presumably) a local variable, leaving it uninitialized results in it holding an unspecified value. In your case, it pointed to an object which wasn't an `NSMutableDictionary`. Actually instantiate one and it will work:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setObject:forKey:`, not `setValue:forKey:`.

```
NSString *Version=[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

NSLog(@"VERSION = %@", Version); //prints the right thing
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dic setObject:Version forKey:@"version"]; //crash 
[dic setObject:Errors forKey:@"errors"]; //work
```

Only use `setValue:forKey:` and `valueForKey:` when you really mean to be using key-value coding. Otherwise use the proper `setObject:forKey:` and `objectForKey:`.

Also, don't use `stringWithFormat:` unless you actually have a string to format.